# Observable Async filter to sort json response by date field in Angular 5 using RxJs

Tags: angular, sorting, rxjs, observable

Observable is capturing an API response looks like below json.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Vijay",
    "effectivedate": "2018-02-08T15:04:46.000Z",
    "expirationdate": "2018-02-22T15:04:46.000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "Thulasi",
    "effectivedate": "2018-01-23T04:42:33.000Z",
    "expirationdate": "2018-01-30T04:42:33.000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "Robert",
    "effectivedate": "2018-01-22T18:42:30.000Z",
    "expirationdate": "2018-01-28T18:42:30.000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "Pakkiyaraj",
    "effectivedate": "2018-02-12T09:04:47.000Z",
    "expirationdate": "2018-02-28T08:48:58.000Z"
  },
  {
    "name": "Violet",
    "effectivedate": "2018-02-20T11:51:27.221Z",
    "expirationdate": "2018-02-22T11:49:37.000Z"
  }
]
```

TypeScript file has the API call and managing the observable to the resonse data.

```
 this.gridResult$ = this.http.get(`**URL HERE**`)
    .map((result: any[]) => {
      return result;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
      this.error.error(err);
    });
```

And My HTML has this snippet.

```
<tr *ngFor="let result of gridResult$ | async">
    <td>{{result.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

I need to sort the json response into the table with date sorting for `effectivedate`. Please let me know if any filter can be used in RxJs.

Comment: you can try using https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth datePipe is used to change the format of the date. Won't help for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

With help of `lodash` and `moment` you can do it like this :

```
var sortedData = _.sortBy(names, function(o) { return  
    moment(o.effectivedate); 
}).reverse();

//OR (With ES6 way)

var sortedData = _.sortBy(names,(o) => moment(o.effectivedate) ).reverse();
```

```js
var names = [
    {
      "name": "Vijay",
      "effectivedate": "2018-02-08T15:04:46.000Z",
      "expirationdate": "2018-02-22T15:04:46.000Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "Thulasi",
      "effectivedate": "2018-01-23T04:42:33.000Z",
      "expirationdate": "2018-01-30T04:42:33.000Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "Robert",
      "effectivedate": "2018-01-22T18:42:30.000Z",
      "expirationdate": "2018-01-28T18:42:30.000Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pakkiyaraj",
      "effectivedate": "2018-02-12T09:04:47.000Z",
      "expirationdate": "2018-02-28T08:48:58.000Z"
    },
    {
      "name": "Violet",
      "effectivedate": "2018-02-20T11:51:27.221Z",
      "expirationdate": "2018-02-22T11:49:37.000Z"
    }
  ];

var sortedData = _.sortBy(names, function(o) { return  moment(o.effectivedate); })
.reverse();

console.log(sortedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.core.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using observable, not an array. I've updated the question. Please refer.

Comment: Still you can do that inside the map function and then return that to observable

Answer (score 0):

You could use standard Javascript sorting in rxjs map directly like following:

```
this.gridResult$ = this.http.get(`**URL HERE**`).pipe(
  map(result => result.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)) // you do your sorting here
);
```

and it will return observable